# Evaluate the indicated trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

Question states: Assume that theta is an acute angle in a right triangle satisfying the given conditions. Evaluate the indicated trigonometric function

$\tan \theta = 1/5;$

What is $ \csc \theta$  equal to ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean $tan\theta$, or "theta".

Answer (score 3):

$$\tan\theta={1\over 5}\implies \cot\theta=5$$

But $$\csc^2\theta =1+\cot^2\theta=1+5^2=26$$
So $$\csc\theta =\pm\sqrt{26}$$
since $\theta$ is an acute angle,  $\csc\theta =\sqrt{26}\approx 5.0991$ is  accepted.

Answer (score 0):

$$tan\theta = \frac15$$

$$\theta=Tan^{-1}\frac15$$

$$\theta = 0.1874$$

$$csc\theta = \frac{1}{sin\theta}$$

$$\frac{1}{sin(0.1874)} \approx 5.099$$

Answer (score -2):

Just draw a diagram where the denominator is the ADJACENT side and the numerator is the OPPOSITE side (recall that $\tan\theta=\frac{OPPOSITE}{ADJACENT}$). With the Pythagoran theorem you can find the HYPOTENUSE. Use this information to find
$$\csc\theta = \frac{1}{\sin \theta}=\frac{HYPOTENUSE}{OPPOSITE}=\dots$$[image]

And remember that Geometry is just as important as Algebra ... you should try to integrate both viewpoints whereever possible.